# Remove storyboard left and right padding on IB

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard

I'm trying to remove the seemingly forced left and right padding on a **storyboard**, need to anchor my view on the border on the Storyboard. Doesn't seem to give me the option to anchor on the border in the interface builder.

Most probably not best practice, but the design looks weird with this padding.

How can I remove the white space on the left and right:

[image]

**Update:**

I have checked the constraint value, its bound at zero on superview. [image]

It only works if I use -20 and 20 for trailing and leading. Need to change superview itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your Storyboard using Xcode and remove the existing Leading and Trailing constraints and add it freshly by Unchecking the **Constrain to margin** checkbox while adding Constraints.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When your on the storyboard select the control you want to have edge to edge, and in the properties window if you select layout you will see the constraints that you've added.

[image: Constraints under 'Layout' in the properties box of your control]

You would want to double click on the 'leading margin space'and set it's 'constant' value to 0 (this can be a bit buggy sometimes, so it may show 0 already, simply remove the 0, re-enter the value 0 and save)

[image: Change the constant value.]

Finally repeat the first step and select the 'Trailing Space' constraint and do the same thing.

once done press on the square icon which visually adjusts the control into it's new constraints and it should be edge to edge.

[image: cosntraints menu at the top of the storyboard interface.]

Comment: thanks for your response - in general I know that would be answer. But my constraints are 0 for everything. From some reason I cannot bind to the edges. Not sure if its a Xamarin IB problem

Comment: @cfl yeah they always show 0, I think it's a weird bug in the Visual studio version of the storyboard interface, just set them to 1, click out of the box, click in the box, set them to 0, click out of the box and save. That will do the trick.

Comment: I did check and changed the value. Updated the question to show this. Not sure if I'm missing something else?

Answer (score 2):

If you are in Xamarin using Visual Studio I finally discover how to tackle this annoying problem.

Click on the widget or view in the storyboard. In the properties window->layout you can see the constraints. Click on the constraint.

Before I was using -20 for constraints:
[image]

Now I fixed by having a constant of 0 and changing the constraint configuration:
[image]

Just remove the selection on the "Relative to Margin" checkbox.